# Организация работы с множеством проектов

Tags: git

Есть множество небольших  проектов - утилит, сервисов, роботов для внутренних нужд. Проекты большей частью живут независимо, некоторые разбиты на отдельные модули слои Data/Logic/UI/Service

Изначально проекты создавались как отдельные Solution но это оказалось не удобно, т.к. достаточно часто в течении дня нужно работать с разными проектами и в этом случае приходится запускать много студий - очень много ресурсов съедается, либо постоянно переоткрывать что тоже не вариант. Также получалось что в проектах часто нужно использовать общую логику что логично нужно выносить в общие компоненты.
В результате пришел к решению - объединить все проекты в один солюшен.
Но в этом случае не удобно работать с git и с каждым проектом как самостоятельно версионируемым модулем.

Думал общие утилиты сделать как NuGet модуль, но это не удобно, т.к. нужны именно исходники.
Git submodules много критикуют, пока не понял стоит ли с ними связываться.

Какие схемы работы в данном случае лучше использовать ? было бы здорово если бы 1 студия умела открывать много солюшенов, но есть и минус в этом случае было бы 30 папок Common на каждый проект своя, возможно для этого есть и другие подходы ?

Использую Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition.

Дополнение :

Специфика такова что Common меняется не так часто и как правило это добавление новых тулзов, например в двух проектах появилась необходимость формировать файлы в одном формате - выносим как Helper в Common, т.е. как правило изменения не деструктивны и можно его не разделять на разные версии. Но есть и проблемные места - иногда нужно изменение сигнатуры и приходится править во всех проектах состояние, еще бывает что зависимость от разных версий внешних сборок. Например раньше была сборка от .net 2.0 при переходе на 4.0 не все проекты готовы собраться.

Answer (score 1):

Вы знаете, я тоже в своё время читал много критики по-поводу submodules, но так и не понял, что в них ужасного. Поэтому взял их на вооружение и бед с тех пор не знаю. Хотя, возможно, при каких-то весьма сложных сценариях они и не очень хороши - я с таким не сталкивался.

Поэтому я однозначно выступаю за submodules, это логичное решение для под-проектов, версии которых не должны зависеть от основного проекта. Соответственно каждый под-проект будет представлен файлом проекта, без solution. Solution это как раз решение для многих проектов, для одного проекта, он, вообще говоря, и не нужен.

Comment: А если сделать из common отдельный проект, который собирать в static lib? Таки образом это будет просто ещё один проект, от которого все другие будут зависеть.